# New-AzureADMSInvitation only for users who aren't already invited

Tags: powershell

been racking my brain with this one. Basically my company has a parent company and we need to connect to their AzureAD. They have given us a service account and I've created a script to go through a CSV and invite the whole company but I'm trying to create a script I can schedule that only invites users who haven't been invited yet by going through our Azure AD.

This is what I have so far, seems to work well except the last most important step, where it's meant to invite the users who haven't been invited yet.

I'd also like to be able to remove users from the parent company's AzureAD when they have been disabled in our AzureAD. Don't even know where to start with that one!

```
# Import Modules
Import-Module MSOnline
Import-Module AzureAD


# Authentication details for your AzureAD
$365Username = "email"
$365Password = "password"
$365pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $365Password -Force
$365creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $365Username,$365pass
connect-msolservice -Credential $365creds


# Authentication details of Service Account
$Username = "service account email"
$Password = "service account password"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $creds -TenantId "tenantID"


# Get your users and email addresses
$Users = Get-MsolGroupMember -ALL -GroupObjectId groupID -MemberObjectTypes User
$emails = $users.EmailAddress


# Find all users already invited
$adazure_user = foreach($email in $emails)
{
    Get-AzureADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ObjectId "$($email -replace "@", "_")#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"

}


# Invite users who haven't been invited yet
foreach ($email in $emails)
{
    #If the user exists, do nothing
    if($adazure_user){}
    #Else if they don't exist, send the invite
    else
    {
        New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserEmailAddress $email -InviteRedirectUrl https://myapps.microsoft.com -SendInvitationMessage $false

        Set-AzureADuser -ObjectId $users.Name"."$users.Surname"_domain.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com” -GivenName $users.Name -Surname $users.Surname
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you executing this: `Set-AzureADuser -ObjectId $users.Name"."$users.Surname"_domain.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com” -GivenName $users.Name -Surname $users.Surname` ? Is that when the user is first created in you AAD? So you know the format for the ObjectId when you set it, then you should be able to search for all users in the file, with the same format. Then you know if you have already invited them or not. Just an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the time to try and understand your code. This solution should work.

```
# Authentication details of Service Account
$Username = "service account email"
$Password = "service account password"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $creds -TenantId "tenantID"


# Get your users and email addresses
$Users = Get-MsolGroupMember -ALL -GroupObjectId groupID -MemberObjectTypes User
$emails = $users.EmailAddress

$nonInvited = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"

# Traverses all emails and stores those that wasn't found in $nonInvited
foreach($email in $emails)
{
    $userTemp = $null

    try {
        $userTemp = Get-AzureADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ObjectId "$($email -replace "@", "_")#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
    catch {}

    if($null -eq $userTemp) {
        $nonInvited.Add($email)
    }
}


# Invite users who haven't been invited yet
foreach ($email in $nonInvited)
{

        New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserEmailAddress $email -InviteRedirectUrl https://myapps.microsoft.com -SendInvitationMessage $false

        Set-AzureADuser -ObjectId $users.Name"."$users.Surname"_domain.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com” -GivenName $users.Name -Surname $users.Surname

}
```

When I did the testing the `Get-AzureADUser` fails badly when it is looking for a user that it can't find. That is why I use the `try {} catch {}` section to help me out.

Comment: Thanks Motz! That worked great! Users are now getting invited!

Only thing is the last bit where it sets the first name and surname which is required with this process seems to not work correctly

Set-AzureADuser -ObjectId $users.Name"."$users.Surname"_domain.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com” -GivenName $users.Name -Surname $users.Surname

Any ideas? I also want to be able to delete users in the parent company azuread who are disabled in our azureAD

Comment: Please share the full solution that you got working, with an update to your question. If you used any of my code to fix the issue, then please accept my answer to close this question :)